Motivating Coequalizers from Set Quotients?
I am trying to interpret the definition of coequalizers as a generalization of quotients by equivalence relations in $\mathsf{Set}$. For products this is rather natural. My notes present an argument akin to that in Smith's category theory book:

Quotients do possess a sort of universal property:

Let $(\pi, S/\sim)$ be a quotient. Then

$\pi$ respects $\sim$: if $x \sim y$, then $\pi(x) = \pi(y)$.
If $\pi(x) = \pi(y)$, then $x \sim y$.
For each $q \in S/\sim$, there exists $x \in S$ such that $\pi(x) = q$.


That is, for each $a \in S/\sim$, there exists a $x \in S$ up to equivalence such that $\pi_\sim(a) = q$. But if we were to interpret these again as generalized elements, we need arrows point to the quotient and $S$, respectively, whereas it is supposed to look like this:

How to make sense of this? Is there some dual notion to elements, and if it exists, why should it be used here instead? Also why does this diagram match that of the coslice category $S/\mathsf{C}$ (with the conditions that functions respect $\sim$)?
I suppose it is possible to generalize from the dual of quotients in $\mathsf{Set}$ instead, but that is a bit unsatisfying not to mention I'm unsure how to do it either.

A universal definition of a quotient looks like:
Given a set $S$ and an equivalence relation $\sim$ on $S$, a quotient is:

A set $Q$
a function $ι : S → Q$, where $x \sim y ⇒ ι(x) = ι(y)$
for every other set $T$ and function $f : S → T$ such that $x \sim y ⇒ f(x) = f(y)$, a unique map $\hat f : Q → T$ such that $f = \hat f \circ ι$

An interesting thing to note is that this specification doesn't actually use the fact that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation at all. So, we could instead define a quotient with regard to any relation on $S$. In that case, the induced relation on $S$:
$$x \approx y := ι(x) = ι(y)$$
would be the equivalence (reflexive-symmetric-transitive) closure of the $\sim$ relation. If $\sim$ is an equivalence relation, it is its own closure, so the induced relation coincides with the original relation. This is a nice property, but not strictly necessary for the specification.
In this light, you can view the coequalizer as a categorical version of this quotient by an arbitrary relation. A pair of functions $l,r : R → S$ induces a relation:
$$x \sim y := ∃z. l(z) = x ∧ r(z) = y$$
And if you take the quotient by this relation, it is the coequalizer of $l$ and $r$ in $\sf Sets$. It's actually possible for $l$ and $r$ to contain some redundant information, but again this doesn't matter for specifying the quotient of sets, only for how certain aspects of it relate back to $l$ and $r$.
If you fiddle around, you can rework the specification of the quotient above to dispense with the relation, by talking about $l(z)$ and $r(z)$ instead of $x$ and $y$. Then you can get rid of $z$ by equating composite functions instead of using point-wise equality. When you do that, you will have the definition of the coequalizer, and can interpret it in any category.

I find this perspective of interpreting parallel arrows as generalized relations fascinating. Indeed, in $\mathsf{Set}$, a homogeneous relation on $X$ is just a pair ($X$, $R$), where $R \subseteq X \times X$. But since $X \times X$ is a product, fixing the inclusion map uniquely determines two arrows from $R \to X$!

The other answers might mostly cover it, but to respond to your question about dual elements, yes, the co-generalized elements of an object $X$ of a category are just the generalized elements of $X$ in the opposite category, i.e. maps out, $X\to Y.$ It's easier to think about quotients in terms of co-generalized elements since quotients are defined in terms of a mapping out universal property. But that doesn't help much with comparing the category-theoretic definition to the set-theoretic construction, which is made out of elements! In general, it can be a quite challenging problem to describe the elements of an object characterized by a mapping-out property. (This is an understatement, insofar as for instance the computation of the homotopy groups of spheres, arguably the most central motivating problem in algebraic topology, is an example of such a problem.)

I am not sure what exactly you are asking, but 3 says that $\pi$ is a surjective, i.e. is an epimorphism in $\mathbf{Set}$. This is not part of the universal property of the coequaliser, but is rather something you can prove from the universal property. Dually, equalisers are monomorphisms (i.e. injective in $\mathbf{Set}$).
